# How to import the text file and put it in HashMap? we need to give code for each company to get details about that company later

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public class Companydatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Companydatabase obj = new Companydatabase();
        obj.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        String File = "nishan.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String split = ",";

        try {
            Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

I could not add each file string to `HashMap`. i wish some one could help me.

```
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(split);
                maps.put(country[0], country[1], country[2], country[3]);
            }

            //loop map
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : maps.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Country [code= " + entry.getKey() + " , name="
                    + entry.getValue() + "]");     
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: At the beginning explain your question and format the code

Comment: Please provide an example of input file content (just several lines) and what do you want to see in the resulting Map.

Comment: The way that you try to `put` values into the map and the way you iterate over them makes me think that `HashMap` might not be the right data structure for you.

Comment: MNT, Mountain View Constructions, 57635444, 5.50
@tagir, input file content are as follows:  \t                                                                                                BNA, Bank of North Antarctica, 23000000, 10.78 
YEL, Yellow Brick Road Paving Company, 30000000, 2.90
ADV, Adventure Time Theme Parks, 68452000, 1.85
CER, Certainty Audits, 850100000, 20.23
EAG, Eagle's Eye Freight Deliveries, 76004000, 7.61

Comment: @simon, i may be using the wrong way. but it is recommended to use hashmap to set key and value from the file companies.dat.

Comment: i want to create a program for stock market which displays company market data from file, displays particular company divident and anouncements. the company file contains company id, company name, number of shares, and price.